# Що таке "меональний"?

Tags: значення-слів, запозичені-слова

У статті [Кісельової Людмили Олександрівни](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%96%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0) "[Семантична мова фольклорної традиції в поезії М. Клюєва та В. Свідзінського](http://ekmair.ukma.edu.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/14358/Kiselova_Semantychna_mova_folklornoi_tradytsii.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)":

> **Меональний** тип опису [20, 55-56] створює систему натяків на основні події, що залишаються поза текстом; а система образів у цілому, апелюючи до «традиційних смислів», забезпечує глибинний підтекст, який певною мірою роз'яснює логіку «стикування» компонентів циклу.

В інтернеті й основних словниках не знаходжу значення цього терміну. Допоможіть зрозуміти, будь ласка.

Answer (score 2):

Такі слова красше шукати за пнєм, цєбто розкладаємо ***меон**·аль·ний*. Про всяк бажано шукати далї впливовими мовами.

Ось наприклад [анґліьською](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meonic):

> Philosophy
>
> Of, relating to, or consisting of a kind of pregnant nothingness or void (as distinguished from an absolute blank nothingness) having the potential to transform into matter.
>
> Origin
>
> 1930s. From ancient Greek μὴ ὄν (more fully τό μὴ ὄν that which is not, nothingness, void (Plato, citing a fragment of Parmenides; from τό, neuter definite article + [μή](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BC%CE%AE) not (from an Indo-European base also found in the Sanskrit negative particle mā) + [ὄν](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%84%CE%BD), neuter present participle of εἶναι to be: see onto-)) + -ic, after Russian [меон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD_(%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F))ический.

Цє штибу порожнечи [чогось], котра має змогу заповнити ся. Шчодо самого виразу: *ме* означає *запереченє* — [нї](http://sum.in.ua/s/ni), а *он* — сутьче, ӧго легко взнати за відомішим словом з тим самим пнєм як [*онтолоґія*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F).

Хоча украӥнською можна теж шчось знаьти, наприклад: перекладають як [*несуще*](http://journals.uran.ua/index.php/2225-7586/issue/viewFile/3303/1032#page=113), [*небуття*](http://vseslova.com.ua/word/%D0%95%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84.)-125609u), [*ніщо*](http://norma.lviv.ua/data/uploads/book/onishenkowww.pdf#page=47).

Цїкаво, шчо [Штепа](https://archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt) наводить:

> меонічний — казковий

Дешчо незрозуміло: перша думка навіює про чогось несправжӧго чи дитячого. Але, на мою думку, цє не зовсїм так, передусӥм, цє *вигадане*, котре не обовязково є суто для дїтеь чи нездїьснене в справжнӧму сьвіті — згадаьте казку про [Голого короля](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F), котра без взагалі чаклунських подїь чи речеь — оркім згадки, але ми теж можемо казати в справжнӧму сьвіті будьшчо. Цєбто дешчо схоже за описом в запитанї — вигадане без згадки реального чи ӧго можливого, тут для прикладу вже згодить ся [Цибуліно](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE) — з наьчарівного лиш самі герої, але ӥх характери чи дїї легко відносно перенести до справжнӧго сьвіту. Отже понятє підходить, але занадто широке, шчо вже не дуже.